# Roblox Studio: Setting the value of ViewportFrame CurrentCamera

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox, luau

Trying to copy the value of the CurrentCamera of a ViewportFrame to change the value of another ViewportFrame's Current Camera.

```
-- Localscript
item.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local EquippedItem = item.Parent.Parent.Parent.EquippedItem

    clientToServer:FireServer(item, EquippedItem)
end)

-- Server Script
clientToServer.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, item, equippedItem)
    local thumbnailCamera = item.ViewportFrame:FindFirstChildOfClass('Model'):WaitForChild('ThumbnailCamera')
    
    print(equippedItem.CurrentCamera) -- outputs nil
    equippedItem.CurrentCamera = thumbnailCamera
    print(equippedItem.CurrentCamera) -- outputs ThumbnailCamera
```

It seems to be changing the value, however visually when pressing play on Roblox Studio, the ViewportFrame is not changing. As you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZuVl.png), when clicking on the first ViewportFrame the second ViewportFrame on the bottom left is supposed to look the same as the one with the blue brick.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a copy of the part or model inside the bottom left ViewportFrame as well. Otherwise, it won't work because ViewportFrames can't share cameras.

Comment: Should I do this in the server script?

Comment: @ReaperIan Yes, Correct. But local script should also work as long as they have their own camera.

Comment: Take a look at this model that I made. https://file.io/5Z6tcYLhuKep

Comment: This worked, tysm, I made a mistake